# Bind iOS framework with inner framework in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I'm trying to bind an iOS framework which contains another framework inside of it.

When I run `sharpie bind` command I get error of **module 'inner framework' not found**.

I tried extracting the inner framework and make separate binding and include the resulted dll into parent framework's bindings.

I could not make it working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi , when separating them you need to be sure each of them expose their public interface and one can invoke another one . If framework designed by yourself , you can combine them into only one to use , not one including another one .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT im not the owner of framework so i guess i can't change the shape of framework. However, both the frameworks have headers exposed which sharpie uses.

Comment: OK, got it .  You should bind one of them successfully first .

Comment: I made separate bindings for both and after resolving the sharpie errors i successfully created dll. But when i ran a test project with the dll it did not give me any error but did not get data from framework either, which it gives when i ran it natively in xcode

Comment: If getting no data , could you set some log print in framework to check code running to where place , this will be helpful to fiind the reason .